# Bluetooth 1200ms delay on Raspberry Pi using bluez (GATT Server)

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, bluez, rust

I have set up GATT server on Raspberry Pi, and I am experiencing huge delay of about, 1200ms. To check delay, I am using nRF Connect on iPhone. I am using Raspberry Pi zero w and bluez bindings for rust.

I have bluez 5.65.

In my Bluetooth config, I have only edited few lines like this:

```
[GATT]
Cache = no
Channels = 1
```

---

Rust GATT server (it only starts advertisement and if it receives data it prints it to console) it is sample code from GitHub(https://github.com/bluez/bluer/blob/master/bluer/examples/gatt_server_io.rs):

```
pub async fn init() -> bluer::Result<()> {
    let session = bluer::Session::new().await?;
    let adapter = session.default_adapter().await?;
    adapter.set_powered(true).await?;

    println!(
        "Advertising on Bluetooth adapter {} with address {}",
        adapter.name(),
        adapter.address().await?
    );
    let mut manufacturer_data = BTreeMap::new();
    manufacturer_data.insert(MANUFACTURER_ID, vec![0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24]);
    let le_advertisement = Advertisement {
        service_uuids: vec![SERVICE_UUID].into_iter().collect(),
        manufacturer_data,
        discoverable: Some(true),
        local_name: Some("mnxd".to_string()),
        ..Default::default()
    };
    let adv_handle = adapter.advertise(le_advertisement).await?;

    println!(
        "Serving GATT service on Bluetooth adapter {}",
        adapter.name()
    );
    let (service_control, service_handle) = service_control();
    let (char_control, char_handle) = characteristic_control();
    let app = Application {
        services: vec![Service {
            uuid: SERVICE_UUID,
            primary: true,
            characteristics: vec![Characteristic {
                uuid: CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                write: Some(CharacteristicWrite {
                    write: true,
                    write_without_response: true,
                    method: CharacteristicWriteMethod::Io,
                    ..Default::default()
                }),
                notify: Some(CharacteristicNotify {
                    notify: true,
                    method: CharacteristicNotifyMethod::Io,
                    ..Default::default()
                }),
                control_handle: char_handle,
                ..Default::default()
            }],
            control_handle: service_handle,
            ..Default::default()
        }],
        ..Default::default()
    };
    let app_handle = adapter.serve_gatt_application(app).await?;

    println!("Service handle is 0x{:x}", service_control.handle()?);
    println!("Characteristic handle is 0x{:x}", char_control.handle()?);

    println!("Service ready. Press enter to quit.");
    let stdin = BufReader::new(tokio::io::stdin());
    let mut lines = stdin.lines();

    let mut value: Vec<u8> = vec![0x10, 0x01, 0x01, 0x10];
    let mut read_buf = Vec::new();
    let mut reader_opt: Option<CharacteristicReader> = None;
    let mut writer_opt: Option<CharacteristicWriter> = None;
    pin_mut!(char_control);

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            _ = lines.next_line() => break,
            evt = char_control.next() => {
                match evt {
                    Some(CharacteristicControlEvent::Write(req)) => {
                        println!("Accepting write event with MTU {}", req.mtu());
                        read_buf = vec![0; req.mtu()];
                        reader_opt = Some(req.accept()?);
                    },
                    Some(CharacteristicControlEvent::Notify(notifier)) => {
                        println!("Accepting notify request event with MTU {}", notifier.mtu());
                        writer_opt = Some(notifier);
                    },
                    None => break,
                }
            }
            read_res = async {
                match &mut reader_opt {
                    Some(reader) => reader.read(&mut read_buf).await,
                    None => future::pending().await,
                }
            } => {
                match read_res {
                    Ok(0) => {
                        warn!("Write stream ended");
                        reader_opt = None;
                    }
                    Ok(n) => {
                        value = read_buf[0..n].to_vec();
                        let value_s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&value);
                        //TODO better names for variables
                        let mut value_vec: Vec<&str>  = value_s.split_whitespace().collect();
                        match value_vec.len(){
                            1 => error!("Missing wifi name or password"),
                            2 =>{
                                    let n_name = value_vec[0].to_string();
                                    let n_passwd: String = value_vec[1].to_string();
                                    let n_passwd: usize = n_passwd.to_string().chars().count();

                                    info!("Network name: {} password: {} - {}", n_name, "*".repeat(n_passwd), n_passwd);
                                },
                            _ => error!("Couldn't read wifi name and password: Too many arguments")
                        }
                       // for s in bob{
                       //     println!("{}", s);
                       // }
                        //println!("{}", &bob)
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        error!("Write stream error: {}", &err);
                        reader_opt = None;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    println!("Removing service and advertisement");
    drop(app_handle);
    drop(adv_handle);
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: A GATT server on RPi Zero using BlueZ bindings should be capable of updating more frequently that this. There is not enough detail in your question to speculate about where the issue is. A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful to see how you have implemented the GATT Server and if there might be issues with the implementation.

Comment: Is the delay is during connection or read/write?

Comment: I think this delay is during read and write